# Maximizing the volume of a cylindrical package given that its length plus girth is at most $84$ inches

Tags: calculus

Postal regulations state that packages must have length plus girth of no more than $84$ inches. Find the dimensions of the cylindrical package of the greatest volume that is mailable.

We know length plus girth $= 2\pi r + h$ so we set this equal to $84$. Then we plug into the volume of a cylinder to get $V=84\pi r^2 -2 \pi^2 2r^2$. What should be the next step?

Comment: There seems to be an error in your formula; for $M = 84 \textrm{ in.}$, we have $h = M - 2 \pi r$, so $V = \pi r^2 h = \pi r^2 (M - 2 \pi r)$.

Comment: If $84 = 2\pi r + h$, then $h = 84 - 2\pi r \implies V =\pi r^2h = \pi r^2(84 - 2\pi r)$.  Differentiate the resulting equation with respect to $r$, then apply the First Derivative Test or Second Derivative Test.

Comment: So once I take the derivative I end up with $4\pi r (21-\pi r)$. Do I set this equal to zero and solve for r to find critical points and determine what the max is?